# Continued fraction of $\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(2^k-1)}{2^p-1}$ for prime p.

Tags: number-theory, continued-fractions

Investigating the q-factiorals. And found experimentally (at least frist 1000 primes) that the continued fraction of $$\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(2^k-1)}{2^p-1}$$ for prime p has level 3 and the last element of continued fraction is equal to $p$.

So:
$$\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(2^k-1)}{2^p-1}=a+\frac{1}{b+\frac{1}{c}}$$
and $c=p$.

If continue:
$$\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(2^k-1)}{2^p-1}=\frac{cba+a+c}{cb+1}$$

so if $c=p$
$$\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(2^k-1)}{2^p-1}=\frac{pba+a+p}{pb+1}$$
Because of Fermat's little theorem, the $b$ is integer.
$$2^p-2=pb$$

Now $pb+1=2^p-1$ and $pba+a+p=a(pb+1)+p$ or $pba+a+p=a(2^p-1)+p$ or
$$\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(2^k-1)-p = a(2^p-1)$$.

So if we prove that the
$$\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(2^k-1) \equiv p \pmod {2^p-1}\tag{*}$$

then we prove the initial idea.

There is also very interesting thing about this
$$\gcd\big(\prod_{k=1}^{p-1}(2^k-1), {2^p-1}\big)=1$$
This and Fermat's little theorem I assume, should be enough to prove the $(*)$ formula, but hang on the proving $(*)$ .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\omega \equiv2 \bmod{(2^p-1)}$, where we have $\omega^p = 1$. It follows that:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{p-1} (2^k-x) \equiv \prod_{k=1}^{p-1} (\omega^k-x) = 1+x+\cdots+x^{p-1}$$
and substituting $x = 1$ yields the product being $p$ modulo $2^p - 1$. Now, it follows that:
$$\frac{\prod_{k=1}^{p-1} (2^k-1)}{2^p-1} = a + \frac{p}{2^p-1} = a + \frac{1}{b + \frac{1}{p}}$$
where $b = \frac{2^p-2}{p}$ is a positive integer by Fermat's Little Theorem.

**Clarification**: The use of $\omega$ is to provide intuition that we our arithmetic matches with that of $p$th roots of unity. It is possible to formalize this notion.

In the field $\mathbb{Q}$, we know that $y^{p-1}+y^{p-2}+\cdots + 1$ is an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb{Q}[y]$. Now, we consider the field extension $\mathbb{Q}[y]/(y^{p-1}+\cdots + y + 1)$. We have the roots of the polynomial $x^{p-1}+x^{p-2} + \cdots + 1$ are the roots of $x^p = 1$ which are not equal to $1$. Hence, they are given by $y, y^2, \ldots, y^{p-1}$. It follows that:
$$\prod_{k=1}^{p-1} (x - y^k) = x^{p-1}+x^{p-2}+\cdots+1$$
However, this means that the identity is in fact true in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/(y^{p-1}+y^{p-2}+\cdots+1)$. It is then also true in $(\mathbb{Z}/(2^p-1))[x, y]/(y^{p-1}+y^{p-2}+\cdots + 1)$. We can substitute $x = 1$ and $y = 2$ to yield the required. Note that we may substitute $y = 2$ since it satisfies $y^{p-1}+y^{p-2}+\cdots + 1 = 0$ in $\mathbb{Z}/(2^p-1)$.

Comment: Note that we are using the fact that $p$ is odd to conclude that $\prod_{k=1}^{p-1} (\omega^k-x) = \prod_{k = 1}^{p-1} (x - \omega^k)$. Indeed, the claim only holds true for odd primes.

Comment: The following is not very clear to me: $\omega \equiv2 \bmod{(2^p-1)}$, where we have $\omega^p = 1$, how we know that such $\omega$ exist. It's late here, may be it is obvious, but can not get in yet.

Comment: Rather than taking it as a root of unity, I am defining $\omega$ to be $2 \bmod{(2^p-1)}$. Now, we have $\omega^p = 1$, but since $(\omega - 1) = 1$, it follows that $\omega$ is a root of $x^{p-1}+x^{p-1}+\cdots + 1$. Now, we have $\prod_{k=1}^{p-1} (x - y^k) = 1 + x + \cdots + x^{p-1}$ in the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x, y] / (1 + y + \cdots + y^{p-1})$, so the required follows by taking $y = 2$. The choice of $\omega$ is to make the idea intuitive.

Comment: Sorry seems I miss what is $\omega$? And $\omega^p=1$ is it modular equivalence?

Comment: It's just the residue $2 \bmod{(2^p-1)}$. The choice of notation was simply to give intuition that our arithmetic is identical to that of $p$th roots of unity. If you like, you may just replace $\omega$ with $2$ everywhere.

Comment: Yes, but then $\omega^p=1$ what does this mean? Is it modular equivalence with modulo $2^p-1$

Comment: Now if we take $\omega=2$ how we get the $$\prod_{k=1}^{p-1} (2^k-x) \equiv  1+x+\cdots+x^{p-1}$$ and which modulo.

Comment: I think I follow your idea, but may I ask to add more details to the answer? So I can accept it?